# drop duplicates based on two criteria

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe reads

```
** | Object ID | Top depth | Base Depth|**
 1 | obj1 | 1500 | 2000 |
 2 | obj1 | 1500 | 1800 |
 3 | obj1 | 1900 | 2000 |
 4 | obj2 | 900  | 1200 |
 5 | obj2 | 1000 | 1200 |
 6 | obj3 | 700  | 800  |
```

I want to drop duplicates but only if it is the same ID with a duplicate top and base depth. for instance, obj1(1) in the first row would be removed as obj1(2) has the same top depth and obj1(3) has the same base depth, obj2 would be left alone because only the base depth is a match.

I was trying to alter the drop duplicates command but I am not sure how to alter it for two true statements i.e. ID & Top Match  AND ID & bottom Match

One of my failed attempts:

`new_df = old_df.drop_duplicates(subset=[('Object ID', 'Top depth') and ('Object ID', 'Base Depth')]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit for further clarification brought to my attention below:
The ones I want to drop are combinations of the two others, it encapsulates the depths. Shallowest is the top depth and deepest is the base depth.

Thanks!

Comment: This is quite not clear. what if there are 4 rows ie `1 obj1 1500 2000` `2 obj1 1500 1800` `3 obj1 1800 2000` `4 obj1 1800 1800` in this case which objects will be dropped and which ones will be maintained?

Comment: @Onyambu Row 4 would drop as well as both the top and base depth are seen in other rows (3,2 respectively).
If top depth is a dup and bottom depth is a dup drop. Does that make sense?

Comment: meaning everything will drop? ie for depth 1500 will be  in 1 and 2, 1800 in 3 and 4, while for base 2000 will be in 1 and 3 while 1800 will be in  2 and 4

Comment: @Onyambu I see what you're saying, the data will not be like that. the ones I want to drop are combinations of the two others, like it encapsulates the depths. shallowest is the top depth and deepest is the base depth. does that make sense?

Comment: but row 2 and 3 also meet the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find duplicates in the first two columns, find duplicates in the first and the last columns. Any thing is duplicate in both of them should be dropped: (Note you should use `keep = 'last'`)

```py
df[~(df.duplicated(subset = ['Object ID','Top Depth'], keep = "last") & df.duplicated(subset = ['Object ID','Base Depth'], keep = "last"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Object ID': ['obj1', 'obj1', 'obj1', 'obj2', 'obj2', 'obj3'], 
                    'Top Depth': [1500, 1500, 1900, 900, 1000, 800],
                    'Base Depth':[2000, 1800, 2000, 1200, 1200, 800]})

df
```

[image]

```
df = df.sort_values('Object ID').drop_duplicates(subset=['Object ID','Top Depth'], keep='last')
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach should work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Object ID': ['obj1', 'obj1', 'obj1', 'obj2', 'obj2', 'obj2','obj2'], 
                    'Top Depth': [1500, 1500, 1900, 900, 1000, 1000, 900],
                    'Base Depth':[2000, 1800, 2000, 1200, 1200, 800, 1200]})

  Object ID  Top Depth  Base Depth
0      obj1       1500        2000
1      obj1       1500        1800
2      obj1       1900        2000
3      obj2        900        1200
4      obj2       1000        1200
5      obj2       1000         800
6      obj2        900        1200
```

```
# drop complete duplicates first
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Object ID','Top Depth','Base Depth'])

# get list of values for Top Depth and Base Depth within the same Object ID
df['Top Depth List'] = df['Object ID'].map(df.groupby('Object ID')['Top Depth'].agg(list).to_dict())
df['Base Depth List'] = df['Object ID'].map(df.groupby('Object ID')['Base Depth'].agg(list).to_dict())

# determine duplicates
df['Duplicate'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['Base Depth List'].count(x['Base Depth']) > 1) & (x['Top Depth List'].count(x['Top Depth']) > 1), axis=1)

# keep only non-duplicates and the original columns
df = df.loc[~df['Duplicate'], ['Object ID','Top Depth','Base Depth']]

  Object ID  Top Depth  Base Depth
1      obj1       1500        1800
2      obj1       1900        2000
3      obj2        900        1200
5      obj2       1000         800
```